# How to add string to option menu X times in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have option menu that come from database, if i add new option menu item that option menu is not refreshed, then i add a ajax success functon to add that menu item to option menu:

```
success: function(results) {
   if (results.ok) {
   list();
   var last_insert_id = results.last_inserted_id;
$('#katID').append($('<option>', {
   value: last_insert_id,
   text: here how can i add result variable times line ?
}));
```

how can i add **result** variable times **- (line)** ?

Example :

if number = 2, then title was: **- - This is title.**

OR

if number = 5 then title was: **- - - - - This is title.**

```js
  $("#katID").change(function(){
      var selectedtext = $( "#katID option:selected" ).text();
      var result = selectedtext.split(" - ");
      console.log(result);
      var number = (result.length);
      var number = (number-1);
      alert(number);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="katID" name="katID">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="0">Top Menu</option>
<option value="96">COMPUTERS</option>
<option value="100"> - DESKTOPS</option>
<option value="101"> -  - ASUS DESKTOPS</option>
<option value="97"> - NOTEBOOKS</option>
<option value="102"> -  - ASUS NOTEBOOKS</option>
<option value="94">TELEVISIONS</option>
<option value="99"> - LCDS</option>
<option value="103"> - PLASMA</option>
<option value="104"> -  - SONY PLASMA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Newer browser you can use the fill method such as: `new Array(7).fill('-').join('')`.  Or: `'-'.repeat(3)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Answer (score 0):

You can run the statement through a simple for loop:

```
var appendTimes = /* Whatever you want the number to be */
for(var i = 0; i < appendTimes; i++) {
  $('#katID').append($('<option>', {
     value: (last_insert_id + i),
     text: "-".repeat(i + 1) + title
  })); 
}
```

Comment: i wanna add simple line -var number- times before title.  similar like this, - - This is title.

Comment: if number = 2, then title was:  - - This is title. OR if number = 5 then title was:  - - - - - This is title.

Comment: @DoganOzer Just use `"-".repeat(i)` to repeat the dash `i` times or `"-".repeat(i + 1)` to add an extra.

Comment: I did it but, how can i append that option to id?   $('#katID').append($this(id).append('<option>', {  similar like this?

Comment: <option value="157">TELEVISIONS</option>  i need to APPEND  under the value=157